# Does the Moon cause rain according to Brahmanda Purana I.2.22.13-21?

Tags: scripture, puranas

Critics of Hinduism use this passage to prove that the Brahmanda Purana says the Moon causes rain. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

As scriptural reference is mandatory, I have searched for several days. Quote from Brahmanda Puran is provided.

From the text- The Sun blazing forth as a purifier, is remembered as Shuci, who pulls moisture from water bodies. Thus by this , the Brahmanda Puran should not be construed to link the moon to rain.

Chapter 24 - The arrangement of the heavenly luminaries

Section 2 - Anuṣaṅga-pāda

Translation of the Brahmanda Purana

23. The sun that blazes imbibing water by means of his rays, is remembered as the divine Śuci (pure) fire that is combined with the terrestrial fire.

24-27. This fire Śuci has a thousand feet (rays). It resembles one holding a pot. With a thousand Nāḍis (vein-like rays) spread all round, it takes up the waters of the rivers, oceans, wells, canals etc. both blowing and stationary.

Its thousand rays exude cold showers, snowfall as well as hot ones. Among them, four hundred veins have variegated forms and they shower (rain).

These veins that cause downpour of rain are named as follows: Candanās, Sādhyās, Kūtanās, Akūtanās and Amṛtās.

28-31. There are three hundred rays other than these and they exude snow. These Veins that bring about snowfall are by name Dṛśyās (visible), Meghās, Yāmyās and Hrādinīs (Rumbling ones).